# Code runs for sometime and then throws Communications link failure Exception MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, scala, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have a Scala code using scalalikejdbc to connect and do INSERTs into MySQL. The code **runs fine for about 2-3 hours** and then throws

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

My connection settings are as below:

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://www.domain.com:3306/schema";

val settings = ConnectionPoolSettings(
               initialSize = 1,
               maxSize = 2,
               connectionTimeoutMillis = 100000L,
               validationQuery = "select 1 from dual");

ConnectionPool.add('dbval, url, username, pwd, settings);
```

Any reason why this is happening and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was opening a new connection before insert and closing it after INSERT. This was perhaps causing some kind of a bottleneck due to too many INSERT queries one after the other.

Resolution: I opened only one connection and added it to the ConnectionPool and used the same connection for every INSERT.